# Videoview redimensionando para o tamanho do vídeo

Tags: android, vídeo

Estou com um problema na minha aplicação, no app eu faço uma sequência de vídeos, mas na hora que fiz a estrutura e inseri o vídeo(não é de muita qualidade gráfica pra o app não ficar muito grande) o VideoView meio que redimensionou e ficou bem pequeno, alguém tem alguma ideia como eu posso resolver isso? Sim eu não me importo se o vídeo ficar feio se ficar pixelado.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<VideoView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/VV1"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="0">




    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnVoltar"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnAvanca"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_weight="2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: poderia postar o codigo do xml desse VideoView?

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, Acho que seja possível fazer isto com VideoView mas outra opção  é usar SurfaceView:
xml:

```
 < SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surface_view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private SurfaceView surfaceView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surface_view1);
   SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer   = new MediaPlayer();
    Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.big_buck_bunny);

    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this,   videoUri);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
}



@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onError() called with: " + "mp = [" + mp + "], what = [" + what + "], extra = [" + extra + "]");
    return false;
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.start();
}
```

Comment: Diniz, obrigado, mas eu gostaria de usar o video view mesmo, não tem noção de como faz não?

Comment: Tenho, já fiz mas não tenho o código, mas aqui tem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310764/videoview-full-screen-in-android-application.

Answer (score 0):

Opa, tudo bem!? a um tempo atrás tive esse mesmo problema... mas era com imagens.

Meu problema era o seguinte: tinha um `imageView` que ocupava uma proporção de 2x1,  dentro de um `LinearLayout`, mas de acordo com o tamanho do celular ficava zoado (pequena, grande, destorcida...), então minha solução foi essa: Coloquei o `imageView` pra ocupar todo o espaço do `LinearLayout`, e defini os tamanhos do linear, no meu caso foi 100% de largura, e 28% de altura. assim a imagem ficou na proporção correta:

```
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearBanner);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams parametros = layout.getLayoutParams();
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    parametros.height = ((display.getHeight() * 28) /100); //nesse trecho do código eu defini que ele ia sempre ocupar 28% da tela, mas no seu caso mude para display.getHeight(), pegando 100% de altura e 100% de largura.
    parametros.width = display.getWidth();
    layout.setLayoutParams(parametros);
```

No seu caso, coloque o `VideoView` dentro de um linear, e set esse codigo acima (esse linearBanner será o seu linear pai, que vai ocupar 100% da tela, ou o tanto que quiser).

Abraços.